# How to inherit a custom view which has a .xib file

Tags: ios, class, xib

There is a custom view, that consist of class and xib file. I use it as

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewNib" owner:self options:nil];
```

Question is how to inherit this custom view.

I inherit the myViewClass, but then I can't use the code above to create a instance.I think I'm in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is not to create `MYBaseView` itself in the .xib file, but it's subview.
This way you will be able to inherit `MYBaseView` easily.

This is the code should work correctly if you create your view object programmatically or in the Interface Builder:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setUp];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setUp];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setUp
{
    UIView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    [self addSubview:view];
}
```

Comment: If in this way, can I link the view in .xib to the MYBaseView?

Comment: No, the view in .xib just a UIView, instead, you should link File Owner to MYBaseView.

Comment: Cool. I iterated the subviews of the nib and added them all as subviews.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
myViewClass *newView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewNib" owner:self options:nil];
```

Comment: This is an array not a view. add lassObject or objectAtIndex:0