# iOS Swift subclassing ViewController initialized by xib (nib) file

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have one base class

```
MyViewController: UIViewController
```

initialized by MyViewController.xib with some outlets. I only have set File Owner class in MyViewController.xib to `MyViewController`, no any init methods in MyViewController.swift (all inherited from `UIViewController`), and following line works just as expected:

```
let vc = MyViewController()
```

view property is set, outlets is set.

I wish to subclass `MyViewController`:

```
SecondViewController: MyViewController
{
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Now I expect that line

```
let vc = SecondViewController()
```

will create view controller with view and outlets inherited from `MyViewController`, but all outlets in vc are nil. Looks like MyViewController.xib file is now missed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336730/subclassing-a-subclassed-uiviewcontroller-that-has-a-xib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't extend the xib file. The `SecondViewController`should have its own xib file and its own outlets. You may define the common UI components in the base class `MyViewController` and for each xib you create, link the ui components directly to the base class.
For example, if you have a common custom back button in all view controller, add the outlet definition in the base class and for each xib file add the `UIButton` and set its outlet to the base class.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Poor to hear this. I believe that subclass system exist not for set same settings in each subclass (what if 100 subclasses with same based UI? I do not want to make 100 same xib files). Probably I don't understand inside cook of init by xib, but for now I see only one good solution - make all base UI in code in MyViewController, not in xib.

Comment: In that case yes, you can create common UI stuff manually in code in the base class OR you can create in a standalone xib file for a different UIViewController and instantiate and add it as a subview